# All my sprites are stuck in the upper left corner?

Tags: sprite, sfml

When I call `sprite.getPosition()` on my sprites I can clearly see that each of them has a different position, but when I draw my sprites every single one of them renders on top of each other?

Here is the full source code thus far:
(I was planning to just pick out the relevant bits, but after 5 minutes of trimming I realized I'd be including 95% of it anyway, so it ends up shorter if I just don't trim it at all)

```
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

sf::Texture spritesheet{};

namespace TextureRects {
    std::array<std::array<sf::IntRect,2>, 3> aliens{{
        {sf::IntRect{0,0,12,8}, sf::IntRect{36,0,12,8}},
        {sf::IntRect{12,0,12,8}, sf::IntRect{48,0,12,8}},
        {sf::IntRect{24,0,12,8}, sf::IntRect{60,0,12,8}}
    }};
}

class Alien {
    public:

    enum class Type {
        one,
        two,
        three,
        max
    };

    private:
    
    enum class AnimationState {
        in,
        out
    };

    sf::Vector2f m_position{};
    Type m_type{};
    sf::Sprite m_sprite{};
    bool m_alive{ true };

    sf::IntRect getTextureRect(AnimationState animationState) const {
        return TextureRects::aliens[static_cast<std::size_t>(m_type)][static_cast<std::size_t>(animationState)];
    }

    void swapTexture() {
        static AnimationState s_animationState{ AnimationState::in };

        m_sprite.setTextureRect(getTextureRect(s_animationState));

        s_animationState = static_cast<AnimationState>(!static_cast<bool>(s_animationState));// in -> out, out -> in
    }

    void initializeTexture() {
        m_sprite.setTexture(spritesheet);
        swapTexture();
    }

    public:

    Alien() = default;

    Alien(Type type) : m_type{ type } {
        initializeTexture();
    }

    void setPosition(sf::Vector2f position) {
        m_sprite.setPosition(position);
        m_position = position;
        
        std::cout << m_sprite.getPosition().x << "\n";
        std::cout << m_sprite.getPosition().y << "\n";
    }

    void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window) const{
        if (m_alive) {
            window.draw(m_sprite);
        }
    }

    void reset() {
        m_alive = true;
    }
};

class Swarm {
    std::vector<Alien> m_aliens{};

    void init() {
        m_aliens.resize(55);

        for (int y{ 0 }; y < 5; ++y) {
            for (int x{ 0 }; x < 11; ++x) {
                if (y == 0) {
                    m_aliens.push_back(Alien{ Alien::Type::three });
                } else if (y < 3) {
                    m_aliens.push_back(Alien{ Alien::Type::two });
                }else {
                    m_aliens.push_back(Alien{ Alien::Type::one });
                }
            }
        }

        reset();
    }

    public:

    Swarm() {
        init();
    };

    void reset() {
        for (std::size_t y{ 0 }; y < 5;++y) {
            for (std::size_t x{ 0 }; x < 11;++x) {
                auto& alien{ m_aliens[y * 11 + x] };

                alien.setPosition({ x * 20.0f, y * 20.0f });

                alien.reset();
            }
        }
    }

    void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window) const{
        for (const auto& alien : m_aliens) {
            alien.draw(window);
        }
    }
};

int main() {

    spritesheet.loadFromFile("spritesheet.png");

    sf::RenderWindow window{sf::VideoMode{448, 512}, "Space Invaders"};// 224x256 * 2x2.5

    sf::View view1{ sf::FloatRect{0,0,224,256} };

    window.setView(view1);

    Swarm swarm{};

    while (window.isOpen()) {

        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            }
        }

        window.clear();

        swarm.draw(window);

        window.display();

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that the `std::cout << m_sprite.getPosition().x << "\n";` and `std::cout << m_sprite.getPosition().y << "\n";` lines print out unique positions for each sprite, yet the output shows every sprite crammed into the upper left corner...
(I know the spritesheet won't load, hopefully it doesn't need to in order for the stack of white squares to be obvious.)

Here's a screenshot of the output in case it saves someone some time:
[image: Image depicting program output]

Comment: When you debug you will see that `alien.draw(window);` has a position of 0, 0

Comment: @MartinSand Yeah I found the issue 2 days after I posted this... I didn't know that `resize()`ing a vector filled it with zero-initialized objects, so it was offsetting all my Alien objects by 55 and causing only the first 55 (zero-initialized) ones to render, and the 55 properly positioned ones were never being reached. I come from JavaScript, so this type of behavior was quite a surprise to me when I finally found out. I don't know why a `resize()` method has such a weird side effect, but I guess I'll never forget now.